# android - android elements used to make this facebook messenger page like imageviews or layout?

Tags: android, facebook

http://www.zwodnik.com/media/images/facebook-messenger_android_1.jpeg

can someone please describe the Android components in this page. please tell what developer has used. ImageViews, Layouts? what they have used to make this page?

Comment: There are Many type view used like LinearLayout with bubble background ,ImageView,TextView,EditText and Button.

Comment: how can we make this conversation view? any idea what he actually used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get this Using the Hierarchy Viewer

- Launch Your App
- Launch the Hierarchy Viewer

and debug your UI

[Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)

Comment: Should I have the code of this app to launch this thing? or even installation is okay?

Comment: just run your FB messenger   and you can get it no need for code :)

Comment: can you please run it and show me the output. its Facebook messenger app actually.

Comment: @RameezK your question been answered so make a minimum effort and follow it

Comment: just try it in your emulator